# NSFetchedResultsController fetchedObjects returning nil

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I used below code fetch the list of `Article` from core data and it is giving me the expected result.

```
    let moc = CoreDataHelper().backgroundContext
    let employeesFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Article")
    do {
    let fetchedEmployees = try moc?.fetch(employeesFetch) as! [Article]
    print(fetchedEmployees.count)
    } catch {
    fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)")
    }
```

> Output : 376

But when I am trying to fetch with NSFetchedResultsController. The fetchedObjects always returning nil. I used below code.

```
 fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Article> = {
        // Create Fetch Request
        let moc = CoreDataHelper().backgroundContext
       // let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Article> = Article.fetchRequest()
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Article")
        // Configure Fetch Request
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"category", ascending: true)]
        // Create Fetched Results Controller
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext:moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        // Configure Fetched Results Controller
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        let quotes = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
        return fetchedResultsController as! NSFetchedResultsController<Article>
    }()
```

The `quotes` is always nil. I am not able to figure out what is the problem?

Comment: You need to `performFetch`.  See [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller/1622305-performfetch)

Comment: Not related but why do you create an unspecified fetch request although you are using a subclass? If you write `let employeesFetch = NSFetchRequest<Article>(entityName:"Article")` you can omit the type cast in the `fetch` line. That's the benefit of the generic type.

Answer (score 1):

try calling performFetch() on fetchedResultsController outside the closure.

hope that will work.